# Bash script to open firefox on successful ping

Tags: linux, bash, ping

As the title suggests I am trying to use bash to ping a server then when it gets a connection it will open Firefox to a page displaying an alarm screen. This will happen after a power down when the computer automatically boots then sometimes can take time to connect to the network. If I set Firefox to start on start-up then sometimes it displays the no connection screen.

Here is what I have already, but it does not seem to stop after a successful ping's.

```
#!/bin/bash

success=0

ping hercules
while [ $success -ne 1 ]; do
    ping -c 4 hercules
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    success=0
                    /usr/bin/firefox
            else
                    success=1
            fi
done
```

I am sure I am doing something pretty stupid and this should no be that hard.

Comment: You are looping when `$success` is not equal to `1` but are setting `success=0` in your success/termination case.

Comment: Thanks everyone as I though I was doing something stupid, the ping out of the while is not needed.

Answer (score 6):

Just to fix your script, you can simply exit the script on success:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ;  do
    if ping -c 4 hercules ; then
        /usr/bin/firefox
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: There's no reason to keep the `ping` out of the `if` statement. `if ping -c 4 hercules; then` will work just fine.

Comment: Not quite. Drop the `[` `]`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to keep pinging. When it succeeds, to start `firefox`, and stop pinging? You are currently setting `success=1` when it fails, and then exiting the `while` loop, as `success -ne 1` is false.

```
#!/bin/bash

success=0
ping hercules
while [ $success -ne 1 ]; do
    ping -c 4 hercules
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        success=1
        /usr/bin/firefox
    fi
done
```

Comment: There's no reason to keep the `ping` out of the `if` statement. `if ping -c 4 hercules; then` will work just fine.

Comment: Agreed. `hek2mgl` shows the cleanest answer. I just wanted to give the OP a modified code that works according to his initial reasoning, but without the "bugs".

Comment: Thanks this did help, I also noticed that I had a ping outside of the while loop which was obviously just running continuously.

Comment: Sure. hek2mgl did the same thing you did originally and I commented there also.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 


ping -t 1 8.8.8.8 #(-t on mac / else it -w)
SUCCESS=0
RETVAL=$?

while [ $SUCCESS -ne 1 ]; do
   if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
    SUCCESS=1
    'LAUNCH FIREFOX HERE IF THE PING WORKS'
   else
    'DO SOMETHING'
   fi
done
```